# How can I change the image displayed in an UIImageView in a cell programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Hi Guys i was wondering how to set the image of an UIimageView that is in a cell. I'm rather new to coding so please fully explain if u can. I currently have this:

```
cell.image.image = [tempObject objectForKey:@"CafeImage"];
```

But the app crashes with this everytime:

`-[PFFile imageAsset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a96cd80 2015-02-22 15:06:19.616 Cafe[12830:140389] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFFile imageAsset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a96cd80'`

Comment: Is cell.image a UIImageViewObject? Unrecoginized selector means you are calling a method that does not exist on the object.

Comment: @Aggressor it's an outlet I made

Comment: You are grabbing the wrong object.

Comment: @Aggressor so how can I fix that

Comment: As mentioned below, you need to grab the imageView object.

Answer (score 1):

It should be cell.imageView.image=[tempObject objectForKey:@"CafeImage"];

Answer (score 0):

first - If you are using a standard cell, you should set

```
cell.imageView.image = "UIImage object";
```

second - Data in [tempObject objectForKey:@"CafeImage"] must be kind of UIImage class, or if it's NSString -> use [UIImage imageName:@"for example - objectForKey"];

Comment: It's a custom cell. image is an outlet I made

Comment: shows us the code where you are storing the image and where you declared the outlet

Comment: Yes!
Please, show code where you are save create/get tempObject.

Comment: What is the structure of the tempObject?